# How to acess the Object of a entity by Id Lambda Expression c#

Tags: c#, api, lambda

I have a function that, based on the user's correct alternatives, should calculate its final score. I would like to calculate different scores for each level (2 points for level 1 successes, 3 points for level 2 successes and 5 points for level 3 successes), and for that I would like to filter through the expression below.

```
public UserScoreDTO GetUserScore(string userId)
        {
            var history = _userQuestionHistoryRepository.GetUserQuestionHistory(userId);
            var userScoreDto = new UserScoreDTO();
            userScoreDto.UserQuestionHistory = history.Select(c => new UserQuestionHistoryDTO {
                AlternativeId = c.AlternativeId, AnsweredIn = c.AnsweredIn, UserId = c.UserId }).ToList();
            //userScoreDto.UserScore = history.Where(c => c.Alternative.IsCorrectAlternative).Count() * 10;
            //This below
            userScoreDto.UserScore = (history.Where(c => c.Alternative.QuestionId == 1 && c.Alternative.IsCorrectAlternative).Count() * 2) +
                (history.Where(c => c.Alternative.QuestionId == 2 && c.Alternative.IsCorrectAlternative).Count() * 3) + (history.Where(c => c.Alternative.QuestionId == 3 && c. Alternative.IsCorrectAlternative).Count() * 5);
            return userScoreDto;
        }
```

However, I don't know how I can, through the id of a question, capture its level, since I would need to do a search for the question by its id and, with that, get the id at its level. Is this possible somehow?

In the code above, I kept c.Alternatuve.QuestionId=1 just to show how far I've come. But I would like to find the question through this Id.

Alternative entity:

```
namespace CollegeMath.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Alternative : EntityBase
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

        public bool IsCorrectAlternative { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Question entity:

```
namespace CollegeMath.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Question : EntityBase
    {
        public Question(string title, int levelId, int contentId, int questionTypeId)
        {
            Title = title;
            LevelId = levelId;
            ContentId = contentId;
            QuestionTypeId = questionTypeId;
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

        public int ContentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Content Content { get; set; }

        public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ImageQuestion> Images { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Alternative> Alternatives { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand (at all) the structure of your classes, so I'll make some general comments.

1. What is the purpose of the question ID? I would think it's to uniquely identify a question.
2. How are you getting the questions? I would assume these are all stored in a file somehow and you're deserializing that file into your application when it starts.
3. Given 1 and 2 above, I would suggest you just load all the questions into a `Dictionary<int, Question>`, where the `int` is the question ID. This solves your question:

> I would need to do a search for the question by its id and, with that, get the id at its level. Is this possible somehow?

Yes, if you define a dictionary as above then you just get it by the question ID as the key:

```
Dictionary<int, Question> questionBank = new Dictionary<int, Question>();
// load your questions
if(questionBank.TryGetValue(questionId, out Question question))
{
    // Question exists, you can look up whatever you want now
}
```

Things I don't understand about your code, that maybe are limiting my ability to assess your situation:

1. Why does a question not have a question ID? A question has a list of Alternative (which could be null!) and only those have a question ID.
2. What is the point in giving an Alternative a question ID when questions themselves don't have IDs?
3. Probably my biggest question - how do you find yourself having a question ID and not just the question itself? If you cached the Question instead of the ID then you'd skip needing to look the question up again (because presumably you pulled it once already to ask it!)
4. What is an Alternative, and maybe related, how do you have a list of Solution? I would think there would be *one and only one Solution* and a (potentially very large) list of WrongAnswer, from which you could draw and populate a multiple-choice question.

Since I don't understand the class structures here I might be missing something but I'd urge you to consider if the class definitions, as written, are the minimum, modular concrete implementations you need.